# How to import from a bucket in the S3 eu-west-1 region?

Tags: cockroachdb

I try to bulk import into a cockroach db from a S3 bucket in the eu-west-1 region

```
IMPORT TABLE osm.nodes (
        id INT PRIMARY KEY,
        version INT NOT NULL,
        lat DECIMAL NOT NULL,
        lon DECIMAL NOT NULL,
        changeset_id INT NOT NULL,
        visible BOOLEAN NOT NULL
    )
    CSV DATA ('s3://cockroach-import/nodes.csv?AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<snip>&AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<snip>')
    WITH
        temp = 's3://cockroach-import/?AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<snip>&AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<snip>',
        delimiter = ','
    ;
```

I get the error message:

```
failed to create s3 reader: 400: "The authorization header is malformed; the region 'us-east-1' is wrong; expecting 'eu-west-1'"
```

How can I specify the S3 region in the import statement?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug that has been fixed in the upcoming release of Cockroach 1.1.2. https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/issues/19435 describes the problem and fix.